# Run as different user from Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, runas, start-screen

In previous editions of Windows you could hold Shift and then Right Click an application from the Start Menu and you would see the "Run as different user" option. In Windows 10 it just closes the menu.

I know if I do it from the desktop/file explorer it works but I would like to get this working from the Start Menu when you search applications.

Comment: See if this helps, you would need W10 pro or higher for this to work...http://www.howto-connect.com/show-run-as-different-user-on-start-menu-windows-10/

Comment: Or this....http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/adding-run-different-user-option-apps-windows-10

Comment: This is still possible.  If its not offered then the group policy that handles is has been configured to be disabled.  I once upon a time wrote an answer to document how to enable it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to enable a registry value to show `Run as different user` in the right-click menu (in Windows 10 Start screen). Copy the following lines to Notepad, and save the file with .REG extension -- for example: `showrunas.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
"ShowRunAsDifferentUserInStart"=dword:00000001
```

Then double-click `showrunas.reg` to apply the setting to the registry. Logoff and login back, or restart Explorer shell for the change to take effect.

Right-click on a Pinned item (pointing to a desktop app) in the Start screen, click `More` and click `Run as different user`.

Comment: This worked. How did you even find this though? There wasn't even a key for Explorer under registry HKCU\...\Microsoft\Windows\

Comment: It's basically a GPO setting available under Administrative Templates > Start menu and Taskbar. `Show Run as different user command on Start`. Some of the Policies registry subkeys don't exist by default.

Comment: Interesting didn't realize that but it makes sense.

Is there a way in Group Policy Management Editor to view which registry key is being modified? How were you able to tell me the key?

Comment: Local Group Policy Editor is available in Pro and higher editions. To see the exact value being modified, use [Process Monitor](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/).

Comment: You can also put this in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE under the same path in order to have it apply to all users rather than the currently logged in user.